# Use PHP to compare a string to a LARGE text file (or... database?)

Tags: php, security, passwords, change-password

I have a PHP 7 login system, and I'm trying to improve password security. I've downloaded the massive (15 Gigabytes!) word list at https://crackstation.net/buy-crackstation-wordlist-password-cracking-dictionary.htm. I want to set it up so that when a user tries to set a new password, it's compared to the word list, and rejected if found on the list.

I don't know how to open such a massive file in PHP and iterate through it without running into memory/resource issues. Can anybody help me with an efficient method for checking a string against such a long list?

(I also have a MySQL database if that helps, though I believe I'd prefer to leave the list as a text file.)

UPDATE: I imagine this would involve some sort of logic similar to sorting routines, to avoid going through the entire list line by line?  That is -- if the password starts with "z" I should jump right to the "z"s...

Comment: Don't load the entire file into memory, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php to read a file line by line.

Comment: Split the file in to separate files for each starting letter. But really why bother with it? Why not let the user choose themselves? I can understand the frustration the user must have when trying a few passwords and they all are rejected due to an list of cracked passwords

Comment: Because the site has a history of users choosing really crappy passwords.  Why does anybody ever try to enforce good passwords?

Comment: I just realized you want to do this every time you change the password.  That would be incredibly slow to read a 15GB file every time they change their password.  You may want to have some more reasonable checks in place, like a general password strength benchmark.

Comment: @Devon Heh. Thus the question! ;-)  Am I totally approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Very good question, I have always wondered why developers enforce password requirements. Historically we did not have any restrictions on passwords at our work, now we have the normal stuff, capital letter, number, non word/digit. I can bet my right arm I can crack at least 100 passwords now with the new rules since a lot of people tried a few times and then gave up and use `company name dot 2018` where the first letter is capitalized. Enforcing passwords make people use as simple passwords as the rules allow.

Comment: @StephenR I can't imagine any efficient way to check against 15GB of data every time a password is changed, but the best way would be to use a database that supports indexing that you can query, not a plain text file that requires you to read the entire contents.   I would think testing password strength is usually sufficient.

Comment: I definitely don't like the whole "at least one upper/lowercase letter, one number, one symbol" routine.  Hell, the guy who came up with that in the first place has popped back up and said it's no good.  So what's a minimum standard?  Minimum length and not found in the dictionary?  (Which dictionary?)

Comment: @Andreas It's only developers that implement it, it's usually company policies and industry requirements (SOC, SSAE, HIPAA) that dictate password complexity requirements.   As a developer, it's usually part of the job to protect the user from themselves and there are still way too many users that use much too simple passwords if allowed.  I'd still way prefer `company name dot 2018` over `password` or `guest`.

Comment: The fact that you appear to know what passwords your users are using hints at much larger, and more pressing security concerns in your application. eg: plaintext or otherwise reversible password storage.

Comment: @Sammitch -- Indeed. Until recently, but now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Crackstation provides a PHP library for creating an index and looking up values. See the instructions here: https://github.com/defuse/crackstation-hashdb.

Lookups are done via the `LookupTable` class: https://github.com/defuse/crackstation-hashdb/blob/master/LookupTable.php

You can also use PHP's support for CrackLib data files:

```
$dict = crack_opendict('/path/to/my_dictionary') or die('Failed to open file');
$check = crack_check($dict, $somePassword);
echo crack_getlastmessage();  // e.g.: 'weak password'
crack_closedict($dict);
```

If your data isn't in one of these formats, you'll need to create an index for your data set to provide efficient lookups. There are several command-line tools that can do this for you such as [SWISH++](http://swishplusplus.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I’ll look into it. Thanks.  I’ve never actually custom compiled PHP

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to come up with a restriction and evaluation pattern that will produce a strong password and find a way to prevent using such list in your system like limiting login attempts by the same ip and rise alart if overal attempts rate rises above the norms because the list can change and increase every day.